# JS, jQuery, how to confirm before deleting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm, confirmation

I have this code to delete a record from a DB-ROW and delete it visually form the html-table.

```
$(function() {
    $('.delpro').click(function(e) {
        var elem = $(this);
        var parents = $('.did' + elem.attr('data-id'));
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'delete.php',
            data: 'id=' + elem.attr('data-id'),
            beforeSend: function() {
                elem.animate({ 'backgroundColor': '#fb6c6c' }, 400);
                parents.animate({ 'backgroundColor': '#fb6c6c' }, 400); 
            },
            success: function() {
                parents.slideUp(300,function() {
                    parents.remove();
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I need a conformation dialog before deleting. I am new to JS and JQuery. How can I do this, and where to place it inside the code?

Comment: try the js confirm `if(confirm("r u sure u want to delete!") == true){\\ur code here}`

Answer (score 2):

Placing it immedietly after click :

```
$(function(){

  $('.delpro').click(function(e){

    if ( confirm('Are you sure') ) { //<--------------- here
      var elem = $(this);
      var parents = $('.did'+elem.attr('data-id'));


      $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'delete.php',
        data: 'id='+elem.attr('data-id'),
        beforeSend: function() {
            elem.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},400);
            parents.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},400);


        },
        success: function() {



            parents.slideUp(300,function() {
            parents.remove();
            });


        }
     });
    return false;
   } //<--------------- here
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks!! Is there a way to make the dialog looks nicer?

Comment: Can also use `if(!confirm('Are you sure')) return false;` to reduce the tabbing, but this is fine too. +1

Comment: @IrkenInvader yeah, your code save a lot, thanks for that.